# Visible elements in a WPF canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, visible, shapes

I have a WPF Canvas and a lot of Shapes (StreamGeometry / Path) added to it. I have ScaleTransform defined to zoom into specific region.

I have zoomed into a arbitrary space in the canvas and the Shapes are scaled. Now, is it possible to get the Shapes that are in the visible region of the Canvas.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.hittest.aspx) to perform a hit test against the Canvas's bounding rectangle.  For details, see [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx) and refer to the sample for [hit testing with DrawingVisuals](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7751).

Answer (score 2):

Should this help?

Iterate thru all children shapes of canvas and check the following for each myShape ....

```
     hitArea
       = new EllipseGeometry(
           new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(myShape), Canvas.GetTop(myShape)),
           1.0, 
           1.0); 

     VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(
          myShape, null,
          new HitTestResultCallback(HitTestCallback),
          new GeometryHitTestParameters(hitArea)); 

     public HitTestResultBehavior HitTestCallback(HitTestResult result)
     {
         if (result.VisualHit == myShape)
         {
              //// This shape is on the visible area.
         }
     }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have been reading about this. How do I get the Top and Left of a canvas? I have added all my geometry objects to a canvas. I'm thinking if I can get the bounds rectangle of the canvas, I can do the HitTest. 


double left = (double)canvas1.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);
double top = (double)canvas1.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);

this gives me NaN.

Comment: Use this... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/281a8cdd-69a9-4a4a-9fc3-c039119af8ed/